# Build executable .jar from spring boot 1.5.3 with gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have  a spring boot project (1.5.3 release) and using gradle 4.4.
I'll build a .jar executable for install a service on linux server.
but I'm having problems generating the executable .jar file.

```
  buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
        //springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4')
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.371'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.370'
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
```

}

How i can generate the .jar?

Comment: what is the problem? did you check in build/libs

Comment: the libs are ok, but coomands like bootJar is not works for this version of spring.

Comment: worth looking into - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

There missing dependency for boot jar.

add this in build.gradle:

```
bootJar {
    baseName = 'application-name'
    version =  '1.0.0'
}
```

command in terminal:

```
gradle bootjar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id "maven-publish"
}
publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId = 'com.your.project'
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
        from components.java
    }
  }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
 }
```

and run command

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

jar file will be generated in local maven repository.